# Skipping a column while grouping odd and even Rows and Columns in a 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a 2 array  and I want to group odd and even numbered    alternating rows and column  ,remove the last column in  odd numbered  and   stack  the arrays .

```
    out_image[:,:shape] = s[::2,::2]
    out_image[:,shape:] = s[1::2,::2]
```

Shape is the middle row/column. Suppose the array is 4094x2048 shape would be 1024.So I would end up with a array of size 2047x2048.

When we have a odd shaped array like 4094x2047 I would like to delete the last column in odd series and group them together. I was able to do this using np.delete but am looking for inplace  solution(array slicing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, which basically removes last column from odd selection by integer division:

```
out_image[:,:shape] = s[::2,::2]
out_image[:,shape:] = s[1::2,:(s.shape[1]//2)*2:2]
```

I would generally suggest this instead of preallocating `out_image` to avoid confusion of different odd vs. even cases:

```
out_image=np.hstack((s[::2,::2],s[1::2,:(s.shape[1]//2)*2:2]))
```